# How to make radius circle in Google Maps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would need to set up in our application a radius circle into Google Maps, something like
[image: here] (pink radius circle).

In the best way I would need to specify how big in miles the radius will be. As our application is written in Ruby On Rails, I am thinking whether will be better to use just Javascript or a gem.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** Attempts:

```
var map;
    var miles = 3;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.476706,0),
          radius: miles * 1609.344,
          fillColor: "#ff69b4",
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeOpacity: 0.0,
          strokeWeight: 0,
          map: map
      });
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),  mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But the map is not inicialized.

Answer (score 3):

Well it's very easy to add a circle to a map with the Maps API, see
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Circle

And then you just need some JS to convert miles to metres.  Multiply by 1609.344 in fact should do it.  So something like this perhaps:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Circle</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map { height: 480px; width:600px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var miles = 3;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.476706, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.476706, 0),
            radius: miles * 1609.344,
            fillColor: "#ff69b4",
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeOpacity: 0.0,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            map: map
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(updated my answer for a fully working solution)

Comment: Thanks `duncan` for your message. I just tried it, but still getting a  blank map. Do I miss there something? (I put it to the OP).

Comment: you've mixed up your MapOptions and your CircleOptions!

Comment: But how to integrate it?

Comment: Ok - one thing yet - why the circle is not nicely rounded like on the screenshot above? I wasn't able to make the circle rounded (there are always edges).

Comment: I don't have this problem, my circles are nicely rounded.  Can you post a screenshot and all your code?